# Output redirection in Android command line

Tags: android, command-line

I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
arp -a
```

and I would like to redirect the output to a file. However,

```
arp -a > arg.log
```

does not work. Any ideas?

Edit: 
I'm using Android 5.0 and the command is executed in /sdcard. The output file arg.log is created but the content is always 0.

Comment: How do you execute the commands? Are you inside adb shell?

Comment: right, inside adb shell

Comment: Do you have write permission in the current directory?

Comment: yes, /sdcard is writable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the problem was that the arp

```
arp -a > arp.log
```

command takes a couple of minutes to complete and the output is flushed at the end.